# "Ну() ведь красота же вокруг!" Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица, междометие

Нужна ли запятая после "Ну"? Каким правилом руководствоваться?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь *нет* оснований для запятой: частица **ну** здесь не выражает побуждения к конкретному действию, не является отдельным восклицанием и потому не требует интонационной паузы. Она просто примыкает к основному содержанию, привлекая внимание собеседника, предлагая ему согласиться с такой реакцией (этому способствует и "ведь", мол сам видишь) и самому как-то отреагировать. Но предшествующий контекст мог бы эту ситуацию изменить, притянув к себе частицу и сделав её побудительной (по желанию автора, факультативно - тогда "ну" будет означать "скорее доставай"):

> Доставай-ка скорее фотоаппарат! Ну(,) ведь красота же вокруг!

Answer (score 0):

Ну ведь красота же вокруг!

Частица  "ну" в восклицательном предложении, паузы нет. Употребляется для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности.

Надо отличать от междометия "ну", которое  обособляется и после которого делается пауза.

Конечно,  междометие и частица близки по значению, общее в них - понуждение к действию: пойти, рассказать, посмотреть, согласиться.

Можно составить предложение с междометием: Ну, посмотри же! Правда, красиво?

Answer (score 0):

[**НУ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_501), междометие и частица.
**1. Междометие.** Выражает побуждение, удивление. Междометие «ну» интонационно отделяется от последующего слова и обособляется.
**2. Частица.** Служит для усиления последующего высказывания; то же, что «так, итак» (употребляется при подведении итогов); то же, что «допустим, положим». Интонационно не отделяется от последующих слов. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

[**ведь**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/145405)
***I*** союз разг.
***II*** част. разг. 
Употребляется при подчеркивании чего-либо сказанного или при противопоставлении сказанного чему-либо другому.

Мне кажется, что пунктуация в Вашем предложении зависит от контекста.
Меня смущает то, что подряд идут две частицы (если писать без запятой), поэтому я бы все-таки остановилась на варианте с ее присутствием.

Предположительный вариант:
— Останемся ещё на денёк? Ну [= решай, соглашайся], ведь красота же вокруг!

*И с просветительской точки зрения это очень важно – должны же люди видеть, куда именно идут их отчисления, что вот – не разворовали их, здания построили, строения. Ну, ведь красотища же, а?* (А. Васильев. Разные стороны)

*— Почему это не получится? — изумилась стрекозка. — У меня всё быстро получается. Медленно я даже не умею.

— Ну, ведь чай пьют не только для того, чтобы вода внутри была...*
[В. Кротов. Озорство и хулиганство](https://books.google.ee/books?id=S5Y0DQAAQBAJ&pg=PT65&lpg=PT65&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F?%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=p1dJ7Y4Xgj&sig=XWrDItf5fpVuJIQJhGtKgDC6rVQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf4KCOtdvcAhVJxKYKHZUqCTwQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%3F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%20%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

> Каким правилом руководствоваться?

Во-первых, важен контекст.
Во-вторых, если Вам известен контекст, попытайтесь произнести это предложение с выражением, соответствующим контексту. Если на "ну" падает логическое ударение (не обязательно даже самое сильное в предложении), тогда междометие "ну" нужно выделить запятой. В противном случае частица "ну" не выделяется запятой.

С учётом восклицательного предложения более вероятно, что "ну" не находится под ударением, но это только статистически, не более того. Пример подобного восклицательного предложения с междометием "ну":

> Ну, ведь мы же помирились! (М.Н. Волконский)